# Why auto merge don't work in bitbacket on this case?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow, automerge

I made such config for branch model

[image: branch model]

After i made release branch and merge it to develop via pull request:

[image: gitbranches]

i was expected auto merge for develop to master but nothig happend.

Answer (score 1):

Automerge work triggers when merge go to master branch.